# GTK-rs getting input from GTK::Entry

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

I have a small `gtk-rs` application where I am trying to display an input field and get the input from the user. At the moment I can't get the input from the input field when the user clicks the button. I know `button.connect_clicked` is where I need to do this but I don't know how?

My build_ui method:

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, Button, Orientation};

pub fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let button = Button::builder()
        .label("Submit")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let input = gtk::Entry::builder()
        .placeholder_text("input")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let gtk_box = gtk::Box::builder()
        .orientation(Orientation::Vertical)
        .build();
    gtk_box.append(&input);
    gtk_box.append(&button);

    button.connect_clicked(move | _button| {
        println!("{}", input.display()); 
    });

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("gtk-app")
        .child(&gtk_box)
        .default_height(720)
        .default_width(360)
        .build();

    window.present();
}
```

main.rs:

```
const APP_ID: &str = "org.my-gtk-app";

fn main() {
    // Create a new application
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();

    // Connect to "activate" signal of `app`
    app.connect_activate(home::build_ui);

    // Run the application
    app.run();
}
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67767061/getting-input-from-a-gtkentry-in-rs-gtk) which is almost exactly the same however when I try and implement the solution all of the .add methods throw an error stating:

```
the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `ApplicationWindow: IsA<CellArea>` which is required by `ApplicationWindow: gtk4::prelude::CellAreaExt`
```

**EDIT:**
Also `Gtk::Entry` does not have a `.get_text()` method according to the compiler. After doing a bit more googling around this it seems that [GTK3](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/blob/master/src/auto/entry.rs#L844) had a `get_text` method for `Gtk::Entry` however [Gtk4](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/src/gtk/auto/entry.rs.html) does not.

So does anyone know how to get the text from a Gtk::Entry object when using Gtk4?

**EDIT 2:**
I think I needed to use the `.display()` method however when I run the code now I don't get the text input from the user. `input.display()` just returns an empty string. I have updated the code samples to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Entry`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/struct.Entry.html) does have a [`text()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.EditableExt.html#tymethod.text) method which gives you a [`GString`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/0.16/docs/glib/struct.GString.html) (because `Entry` implements [`Editable`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/struct.Editable.html)), that can be converted to a rust [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) using [`as_str()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/0.16/docs/glib/struct.GString.html#method.as_str).

So in order to get the current text from an entry, you can do the following:

```rust
let my_input_value = my_input.text().as_str();
```

For completeness, here is the updated `build_ui` function:

```rust
pub fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let button = Button::builder()
        .label("Submit")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let input = gtk::Entry::builder()
        .placeholder_text("input")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    let gtk_box = gtk::Box::builder()
        .orientation(Orientation::Vertical)
        .build();
    gtk_box.append(&input);
    gtk_box.append(&button);

    button.connect_clicked(move | _button| {
        println!("{}", input.text().as_str()); 
    });

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("gtk-app")
        .child(&gtk_box)
        .default_height(720)
        .default_width(360)
        .build();

    window.present();
}
```

### Edit

Because `GString` implements [`Display`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/struct.GString.html#impl-Display-for-GString) the following works as well:

```rust
println!("{}", input.text());
```